# url decryption in apache webserver

Tags: php, apache, url

I am trying use php code to encrypt the url, but Apache server sending 404 error . do we need to make any configuration change on Apache server to understand encrypted URL. These are dynamic query hence i cannot rewrite the url in Apache

**original URL**

http://mywebserver.com/test/launch?cmd=showMain&j_username=guest&j_password=guest

**encrypted URL**

http://mywebserver.com/test/bGF1bmNoP2NtZD1zaG93TWFpbiZqX3VzZXJuYW1lPWd1ZXN0JmpfcGFzc3dvcmQ9Z3Vlc3Q=

```
192.168.10.20 - - [30/Apr/2017:17:35:34 +0800] "GET /test/__1L3N3Zm9iamVjdC5qcw== HTTP/1.1" 404 324 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0"
192.168.10.20 - - [30/Apr/2017:17:35:57 +0800] "GET /test/__1c3dmb2JqZWN0Lmpz HTTP/1.1" 404 320 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0"
192.168.10.20 - - [30/Apr/2017:17:36:20 +0800] "GET /test/__1c3dmb2JqZWN0Lmpz HTTP/1.1" 404 320 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0"
```

Comment: How was the original URL working, did you rewrite `launch` requests?

Comment: no original is working fine without any issue. this without any rewrite , you can see  its passing user name and password in the url hence i am trying to hide this. this is HP nnmi application call

Comment: `launch` is a directory then with a defined document root?

Comment: "I am trying use php code to encrypt the url" — What code? Did you write it yourself? Did it come with instructions?

Comment: here i am trying to use apache reverse proxy , instead of using nnmi direct url (http://<host>:<port>/nnm/launch?cmd=showMain&j_username=guest&j_password=guest ) and trying to mask user name and password.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9Bnt.png i have uploaded HP doc, here you can see HP suggesting to pass username add password via url , Hence i am trying to use apache reverse proxy to hide/ mask user credentials.

Comment: Base64 is **not** encryption, it is an encoding. There is no security in Base64 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the Base64 encoded information a query string by preceding it with a `?`. The `?` needs to be outside the Base64 encoded information, not in it.

Comment: user > code to encrypt the query value + i frame code to load NNMI  > Apache Reverse proxy > HP NNMi server please see this is request flow but where i can decode Base64 value before passing to HP NNMi